# PySpark: Flag rows of specific columns in df1, that exist in df2?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Im using Pypsark. I have two dataframes, call them df1 and df2. I want df1 to create a new column to flag what rows of df1's columns (A, B) exist and do not exist in df2's columns D,E. 1 marking existence and 0 otherwise. An example of the transformation is:

### df1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

### df2

| D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

### Resulting df1

| A | B | C | Exist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

The focus columns from df1 are A,B and for df2 are D, E. Only the second row of these columns match so df1 has its newly created exist column marked as 1.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can check my answer in your another post which is similar like this

Answer (score 0):

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")

spark.sql("select a,b,c, case when d is null and e is null then 0 else 1 end exist from table1 left outer join table2 on A=D and B=E").show()

Comment: Can you give the code? I have no idea how to translate whats inside the sql() into PySPark code.

Comment: above is a pyspark code .you can call spark.sql inside the pyspark. run it in you pyspark window it will work